# RuntimeError: Torch is not able to use GPU after using higher steps with stable diffusion

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, torch, stable-diffusion

After using higher amount of steps than before (35 instead of 20) SD crashed and is showing me this error, after deleting, installing and running it again:

```
################################################################
Install script for stable-diffusion + Web UI
Tested on Debian 11 (Bullseye)
################################################################

################################################################
Running on marcel user
################################################################

################################################################
Repo already cloned, using it as install directory
################################################################

################################################################
Create and activate python venv
################################################################

################################################################
Launching launch.py...
################################################################
Using TCMalloc: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun  9 2023, 07:59:55) [GCC 12.3.0]
Version: v1.5.1
Commit hash: 68f336bd994bed5442ad95bad6b6ad5564a5409a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcel/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/marcel/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 29, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "/home/marcel/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 314, in prepare_environment
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Torch is not able to use GPU; add --skip-torch-cuda-test to COMMANDLINE_ARGS variable to disable this check
```

I tried to follow [This advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910666/how-to-solve-torch-is-not-able-to-use-gpuerror) but it is still showing me the same error message.
I changed/added the said command in: `launch.py`,`webui.bat` and `webui-user.bat`

I do not understand in which file to add the command, or is it perhaps a completely different issue?

I am using Linux Ubuntu 23.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P15s Gen 2i with a `11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 × 8` Processor and `NVIDIA T500 / Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)` Graphics
with Python 3.11.4 installed